# How to switch to another user's branch using git bash

Tags: git, repository, git-bash

I am working on a GitHub project and I am trying to switch from master to another user's branch. Their branch is ahead of master and has multiple changes. No matter what I try, I cannot switch to their branch and get their changes.

I have tried numerous gitbash commands including checkout, pull, clone, fetch.

```
git clone link
git checkout branchName
git fetch branchName
git fetch
```

I expected "git checkout branchName" to switch to the other user's branch, but it just switches to a brand new local branch with the same name. "git fetch branchName" just returns an error.

I have been using git for years and I feel like an idiot that I cannot figure this out. I also cannot find the solution anywhere online.

Comment: There is no such thing as "some other user's branch". Your repository is *yours*, and all your branches are *yours*. Your Git will remember some other Git's branches via *your* remote-tracking names (e.g., `origin/theirbranch`) and you can make your own branch, which you can *name* `theirbranch` if you like but it's still your branch, that points to the same commit as `origin/theirbranch`. Git is really about *commits* though: the branch names only exist to *remember* a commit. So don't worry too much about the names.

Comment: As EncryptedWatermelon suggests, you can check out a commit by something other than a branch name, e.g., by the remote-tracking name `origin/theirbranch`. Git calls this state a *detached HEAD*. You're on the *commit*, rather than being on any branch. You're on *no* branch. That's fine! Git just won't be able to remember *new* commits you make, because branch names are how Git remembers commits.

Comment: (This isn't a completely accurate picture—for that, we have to go into Git's concept of a *reference*, of which branch names are just one kind—but it should get the general idea across: that Git is really about *commits*.)

Comment: @torek you are just wrong. This is a project that is owned by another user, and there are 6 people actively working on it. You just made a condescending response that was completely missing the point of my question.

Comment: It's not meant to be condescending, and it's literally true: once you clone a repository, that repository is *yours*, to do with as you will. Your Git's names are all yours. The remote-tracking names—`origin/foo`, `upstream/bar`—are also yours, they're just slaved from some other, independent Git repository. Running `git fetch` to that particular remote updates your remote-tracking names, while also obtaining any commits they have that you don't.

Answer (score 1):

`git checkout <other_users_remote>/branchName` or `git checkout -b branchName <other_users_remote>/branchName` to create a tracking branch

Did you add the other person's remote? `git remote -v`

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. None of the answers seemed to understand my situation so I will reiterate. I am working on a project with multiple other users. They all have their own branches with commits on each, all stemming from master. I want to switch to another user's branch and then help work on their current branch.

To do this I needed to do the command:

```
git fetch origin branchName:branchName
```